# How do I pass information between BroadcastReceiver and main method

Tags: java, android, methods, broadcastreceiver

In a SMS aplication I want to pass a value of a String from de BroadcastReceiver to the main method.

```js
public class LucesAlarma extends AppCompatActivity {

IntentFilter intentFilterLA;

    private BroadcastReceiver intentRecieverLA = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {

                final String MENSAJE = intent.getExtras().getString("mensaje");
                String NUMERODELMENSAJE  = intent.getExtras().getString("numero");
            }
        };

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

        {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_luces_alarma);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    intentFilterLA = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilterLA.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
          //I want to use the String Mensaje from the BroadcastReceiver  here
        }

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    registerReceiver(intentRecieverLA, intentFilterLA);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    unregisterReceiver(intentRecieverLA);
    super.onPause();
}

}
```

Here is the SMS receiver code

```js
public class ReceptorSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[]messages=null;
        String str = "";
        String num = "";
        String men = "";
        if(bundle != null)
        {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            assert pdus != null;
            messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i=0 ; i<messages.length;i++)
            {
                messages[i]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                num = messages[i].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                str += "Mensaje de" +messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += ":";
                str += messages[i].getMessageBody();
                str += "\n";
                men = messages[i].getMessageBody();

            }
            //           Toast.makeText(context,str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
            broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
            broadcastIntent.putExtra("sms", str);
            broadcastIntent.putExtra("mensaje", men);
            broadcastIntent.putExtra("numero", num);
            context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }


    }
}
```

Please I want to know how to get that String into the main methot.

Comment: That `BroadcastReceiver` won't get any broadcasts until the `Activity` is up and running, at which point the `onCreate()` method is already done.

Comment: I agree with @Mike M and you have to register and unregister the broadcast Receiver

Comment: more code and info is needed to get the correct solution @Josue Manuek Pareja Contreras

Comment: I am new programming, I want to know how I can pass the String content to the inCreate().

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to start activity when receive any SMS, than you should do like this

in your `ReceptorSMS` class

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{.
 .
 .
        Toast.makeText(context,str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent .setClassName("<YOUR PACKAGE NAME>", "<YOUR PACKAGE NAME>.LucesAlarma");
        broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("sms", str);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("mensaje", men);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("numero", num);
        context.startActivity(broadcastIntent);
    }
```

after that in `onCreate`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String sms= intent.getStringExtra("sms");
String men = intent.getStringExtra("mensaje");
String num = intent.getStringExtra("numero");
```

Comment: I want to recieve the messages on the BroadcastReceiver intentRecieverLA, and pass the content of String MENSAJE to the onCreate without using the intent in the "onCreate". Thanks for the aswer.